# C# - Create instance of all sub classes of a generic base class via Reflection

Tags: c#, generics, system.reflection

I want to create instances of all classes which are sub classes of a generic base class. I have searched for some time now. Didn't find anything.

```
public class BaseClass<T> { }
public class CustomSubClass: BaseClass<int> { }
```

I have problems with the generic type. Anyone who can help me?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you try to iterate over all types and create instances with: object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type); ?

Comment: Are all the sub classes located in the same assembly?

Comment: All sub classes are located in the same assembly. I have tried to CreateInstance but I get a message saying that it cant create instance because of the generic T.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have:

```
class BaseClass<T> { }

class CustomSubClass : BaseClass<int> { }

class CustomSubClass2 : BaseClass<string> { }
```

Then :

```
List<Type> allSubTypes = new List<Type>();
foreach(var assem in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
{
    var subTypes = assem.GetTypes().Where(x => x.BaseType != null 
                         && x.BaseType.IsGenericType 
                         && x.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(BaseClass<>));

    allSubTypes.AddRange(subTypes);
}

// CustomSubClass and CustomSubClass2
foreach (var type in allSubTypes)
{
    object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
}
```

Comment: Additional information: Cannot create an instance of  MYCLASS because Type.ContainsGenericParameters is true.

Comment: Can you show your constructor if you have one. Edit your question and add it. It is working from my side.

Comment: Ah it failed for a specific class which is a bit different. It works like a charm! :-)  Thank you!

Comment: @redlaz if you want to create a class that has a generic type argument. Then you have to use `type.MakeGenericType(typeof(int));` for example.

Comment: Yup. It was a class which had a generic type. Than you again!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are implementing a plugin system of some kind. You might want to check out [MEF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648(v=vs.110).aspx) which does this kind of thing for you;

"The Managed Extensibility Framework or MEF is a library for creating lightweight, extensible applications. It allows application developers to discover and use extensions with no configuration required. It also lets extension developers easily encapsulate code and avoid fragile hard dependencies. MEF not only allows extensions to be reused within applications, but across applications as well."

Answer (score 0):

having the same question, I end up here.
But also looking [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52170800/dynamically-instantiate-classes-extending-baseclass-using-reflection) too.

So I end up with this draft of code merging both part :

```
// Get all derivative class of BaseClass<T>
    var allSubTypes = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        .SelectMany(a=>a.GetTypes())
        .Where(x => x.BaseType != null
                             && !x.IsAbstract
                             && (x.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null)
                             && x.BaseType.IsGenericType
                             && x.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(BaseClass<>));

    // and instantiate them
    foreach (var type in allSubTypes)
    {
        object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    }
```