# Dynamically instantiate classes extending baseclass using reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, system.reflection, decoupling

For a long time I have been struggling with finding a way to dynamically instantiate all classes that extends a specific baseclass (during runtime). From what I have read, it is supposed to be done using `Reflection`, unfortunately I haven't figured out how yet.

My project structure looks like this:

```
Library
--|
  |
  --Vehicle.cs (abstract class)
  |
  --Car.cs (extending vehicle)
  |
  --Bike.cs (extending vehicle)
  |
  --Scooter.cs (extending vehicle)
  |
  --InstanceService.cs (static class)
  |
  |
ConsoleApplication
--|
  |
  --Program.cs
```

The **InstanceService** class contains a generic method which is supposed to return an `IEnumerable<T>` containing the instantiated classes extending `Vehicle`, meaning `Car, Bike & Scooter`.

The code posted bellow is the current state of the **InstanceService** class, after having tried a ton of different solutions, meaning it mostly contains tools for debugging.

**InstanceService.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Library
{
    public static class InstanceService<T>
    {
        //returns instances of all classes of type T
        public static IEnumerable<T> GetInstances()
        {

            var interfaceType = typeof(T);
            List<T> list = new List<T>();
            Console.WriteLine("Interface type: " + interfaceType.ToString());
            var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
            foreach(var assembly in assemblies)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Assembly: " + assembly.ToString());
                if (assembly.GetType().IsAbstract)
                {
                    var instance = (T) Activator.CreateInstance(assembly.GetType());
                    list.Add(instance);
                }
            }
            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

I have also attached the code for the abstract `Vehicle` class as well as one of the implementations of it.

**Vehicle.cs**

```
namespace Library
{
    public abstract class Vehicle
    {
        protected float maxSpeedInKmPerHour;
        protected float weightInKg;
        protected float priceInDkk;
    }
}
```

**Car.cs**

```
namespace Library
{
    public class Car : Vehicle
    {

        public Car()
        {
            this.maxSpeedInKmPerHour = 1200;
            this.weightInKg = 45000;
            this.priceInDkk = 71000000;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is it that is (specifically) going wrong with this current approach?

Comment: Nothing specific, atleast it is not returning any errors. I am just curios as to how this is achieved in the best possible way.

Also, with the current approach, the function only seems to be returning a single object which cannot be looped through, when in fact it should return a List containing 3 instantiated classes derived from `Vehicle`. Then I use `ToString()` on the list returned by the function, I get the following output `System.Collections.Generic.List1[Library.Vehicle]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the method that should interest you is [`IsAssignableFrom`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isassignablefrom?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Also, the code is much easier with LINQ, if you're allowed to use that, and since you're creating the objects one at a time, I suggest using [`yield return`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield).

```
static IEnumerable<T> GetInstances<T>() 
{
    var baseType = typeof(T);
    var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        .SelectMany( a => a.GetTypes() )
        .Where
        (
            t => baseType.IsAssignableFrom(t)                  //Derives from base
              && !t.IsAbstract                                 //Is not abstract
              && (t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null)   //Has default constructor
        );


    foreach (var t in types)
    {
        yield return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
    }
}
```

Or if for some reason you're showing off and you want to do it with one statement:

```
    var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        .SelectMany( a => a.GetTypes() )
        .Where
        (
            t => typeof(T)IsAssignableFrom(t)  
              && !t.IsAbstract 
              && (t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null) 
        )
        .Select
        (
            t => (T)Activator.CreateInstance(t)
        );
```

Comment: You are a champ! This works like a charm, and is easily understandable. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This should work for any type that can be instantiated using a default constructor.  The fact that your classes are derived from another class is beside the point, unless I'm missing something...

```
private T MakeInstance<T>()
{
    // the empty Type[] means you are passing nothing to the constructor - which gives
    // you the default constructor.  If you need to pass in an int to instantiate it, you
    // could add int to the Type[]...
    ConstructorInfo defaultCtor = typeof(T).GetConstructor(new Type[] { });

    // if there is no default constructor, then it will be null, so you must check
    if (defaultCtor == null)
        throw new Exception("No default constructor");
    else
    {
        T instance = (T)defaultCtor.Invoke(new object[] { });   // again, nothing to pass in.  If the constructor needs anything, include it here.
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: But with this approach you only seem to be creating one instance? I suppose the approach is a bit different when I am creating instances of all classes derived from the baseclass?

Comment: Yes, this creates one instance.  If you want more than one instance of a specific type, you can run it in a loop and add them to a collection as they are instantiated.  I'm not quite sure what you're going for here - if you want a new one of each, then John Wu's approach would work better, but unless you are constantly adding classes, I would just instantiate one of each manually and avoid using reflection and generics like InstanceService<T> (which are both designed for cases when you DON'T know the data type you want at compile time - it sounds like you DO know up front)

Comment: Yes, that is correct. However it is unrelated what I want, as this is an assignment, and not an actual application. And in the assignment the following is specified: _Create an InstanceService  with the method_ `IEnumerable<T> GetInstances()` _which returns an instance of all classes of type T_